# Change style of selected cluster using MarkerClusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have flowing situation. There are some markers on map that are on exactly the same lat/lng so MarkerClusterer zooming do not break cluster. I handled users click, but I would like to set different image for clicked cluster.

I found `setStyles()` method but that one changes default style set for cluster generation.

I tried something along these lines:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, duplicateMarkers);
markerCluster.clusters_[0].clusterIcon_.url_ = imageurl;
```

I set different image but it does't change on map, also tried puting in in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem or just ended up changing the UX?, I'm using MarkerClustererPlus and it has the same limitation

Answer (score 0):

You can define styles when creating the cluster.

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker_list, {styles:[{...},{...},,,]});

See the example here for how to define custom styles: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html

You would need to extend that concept and find a way to distinguish or identify when to use the different icon.
In my case, I have 5 different types of markers on my map, and I want 5 different types of clusters (one for each type of marker).  I have my markers sorted in five different arrays.
In your case, you would want to add the markers with same lat/long to two different arrays (markerArray1 and markerArray2, for example).
Then do:
var markerCluster1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray1, {styles:[{...},{...},,,]});

var markerCluster2 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray2, {styles:[{...},{...},,,]});

so, you are defining the clusters separately, with different styles, but adding them to the same map.